# How to get rid of "Unable to create an object of type DbContext" error while creating a migration with EF Core 5?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, migration

Hello i have a read model in my application where i need to use EF Core migration system. My database provider is PostgreSQL. I have a context class which derives from DbContext:

```
public sealed class UserReadModelContext : DbContext                           
{                                                                              
    public const string SchemaName = "UserContextReadModel";                   
                                                                               
    public UserReadModelContext(DbContextOptions<UserReadModelContext> options)
        : base(options)                                                        
    {                                                                          
    }                                                                          
                                                                               
    public DbSet<Entities.User> Users { get; set; }                            
                                                                               
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)         
    {                                                                          
    }                                                                          
}
```

My context is registered with the following methods:

```
internal static IServiceCollection AddReadModelDependencies(this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration configuration) =>
        services
            .AddDatabaseContext<UserReadModelContext>(configuration,
                DatabaseProvider.PostgreSQL,
                true,
                UserContextConnectionStringSectionKey,
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)
            .AddScoped<IUserReadModelRepository, UserReadModelRepository>();
...
public static IServiceCollection AddDatabaseContext<TContext>(this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration configuration,
    DatabaseProvider provider,
    bool useHealthCheck,
    string connectionStringSectionName,
    string migrationAssemblyName = null) where TContext : DbContext
{
    var connectionString = configuration
        .GetConnectionString(connectionStringSectionName);

    var databaseContextOptionsAction = CreateContextOptions(provider,
        connectionString,
        migrationAssemblyName);

    return services
        .AddDbContext<TContext>(databaseContextOptionsAction)
        .ConfigureHealthChecks<TContext>(useHealthCheck,
            provider,
            connectionString); 
}
...
private static Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> CreateContextOptions(DatabaseProvider provider,
    string connectionString,
    string migrationAssemblyName = null) =>
        provider switch
        {
            DatabaseProvider.SqlServer => migrationAssemblyName != null
                ? (Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>) (optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder
                    .UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                        sqlServerOptionsBuilder =>
                            sqlServerOptionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssemblyName)))
                : (DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString),
            DatabaseProvider.PostgreSQL => migrationAssemblyName != null
                ? (Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>) (optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder
                    .UseNpgsql(connectionString,
                        postgresOptionsBuilder =>
                            postgresOptionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssemblyName)))
                : (DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(connectionString),
            _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(DatabaseProvider))
        };
```

I also attach the User class:

```
public abstract class Entity : IIdentifiable
{
    protected Entity(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
}
...
[Table("Users", Schema = UserReadModelContext.SchemaName)]
public sealed class User : Entity
{
    public User(Guid id,
        string login,
        byte[] password,
        string firstName,
        string lastName,
        string mailAddress)
            : base(id)
    {
        Id = id;
        Login = login;
        Password = password;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        MailAddress = mailAddress;
    }
    
    public string Login { get; }
    public byte[] Password { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
    public string MailAddress { get; }
}
```

While i am trying to create a new migration, an error is being logged to the terminal: "Unable to create an object of type UserReadModelContext". I've specified the startup-project correctly. How can i solve such an error? Thanks for any answer.

Comment: How do you try create a migration? With `dotnet ef migrations add MyMigration`?

Comment: Exactly, "dotnet ef migrations add NAME --stratup-project STARTUP_PROJECT --context UserReadModelContext -o OUTPUT_DIR"

Comment: It's like the DI can't create the class `UserReadModelContext`. Maybe if you modify the constructor signature to `UserReadModelContext(DbContextOptions options)`.